# Writing the data to second column across different rows of excel (mapping aspect to respective sentence)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data with which I find the aspect of the sentences and write it to the excel file. The image attached shows the Verbatim, which is the input and Aspect column in the Output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyzFL.png)

Below is the piece code of reading input and writing the output to the file.

```
def main():
    result=[]
    with open("ascept.csv",'r') as fin:
                sent=fin.read()
                for values in sent.split("\n"):
                    np_extractor=NPExtractor(values)
                    result=(np_extractor.extract())
                    wb=load_workbook("ascept.xlsx")
                    ws=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
                    r=2
                    for item in result:
                        ws.cell(row=r,column=2).value=item
                        r+=1
                    wb.save("ascept.xlsx")
```

Could anyone help me with the logic to write the respective aspect to the respective sentence. The above code writes character wise to the file (Not implemented any logic to match the sentence and aspect).